# How to convert it to a date format in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to convert this time `2021-08-16 12:58:00.000` to a `DateTime` this way:

```
SELECT Convert(datetime, '16/08/2021 12:58:00:000PM');
```

And getting "Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.".

What am I doing wrong? Is it an invalid date time?

Comment: `'2021-08-16 12:58:00.000'` and `'16/08/2021 12:58:00:000PM'` aren't the same value. Though I suspect you are using [American] English for your `LOGIN` and thus the conversion fails. Have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on `CONVERT`; it lists all the style codes and you should easily be able to spot the one you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your date is formatted at dd/mm/yyyy and SQL Server expects it as mm/dd/yyyy. In fact, if you do this it will succeed:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '08/16/2021 12:58:00:000PM');
```

To make it work for your format, you need to pass a style value to let SQL Server know the format you are using. For your example, this works:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '16/08/2021 12:58:00:000PM', 103);
```

103 corresponds to dd/mm/yyyy. You can see a full list of style values in the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15